# need jquery video file uploader example

Tags: jquery, video, uploader

i need jquery video file uploader example.so,that i can upload images and delete it dynamically.

Comment: http://www.uploadify.com/ should be your best bet.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are couple of good jQuery plugins.

http://www.uploadify.com/demos/

http://www.webdeveloperjuice.com/2010/02/13/7-trusted-ajax-file-upload-plugins-using-jquery/

http://www.fyneworks.com/jquery/multiple-file-upload/

However you need a server side page(ASP / PHP/ ASP.NET etc...) to accept the http request(which comes from this jquery plugin) and save the file to hard disk /save an entry in your table about the uploaded files.